# How is で used in ＭＶＰで言ったら

Tags: meaning, sentence

> A:早いとこ結婚したらどうだ。
> B:「ウィー・アー・ザ・ワールド」のブルーススプリングスティーンより唐突だな。
> B:アル・ジャロウの後に入ってくるやつな。ビックとなるような初見。
> A:でも**ｍｖｐで言ったら**ブルーススプリングスティーンだと思うけどな。
> B:たしかに後半のスティービーワンダーに一歩も引かないあの姿勢はすごいけど。

What I had come up was that で is an abbreviation of 中で, but I don't understand what MVP refers to, the 45 singers? So I thought maybe it meant something along the lines of

> "Among the MVPS (45 singers) it was Bruce Springsteen (that made me ビックとなる)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

で is a particle that can broadly mark a scope/condition (e.g., 合計で "in total", 1人で "alone", 3人の中で最強 "strongest among the three of them"). So Xで言ったら describes what the speaker is going to talk about. It means "speaking of X", "when it comes to X", "X-wise", "in terms of X", etc. This is a set phrase that only comes at the beginning of a sentence.

> それで言ったら、...
>
> In that sense, ...
> Speaking of which, ...

MVPで言ったら in this context effectively means "If I were to choose an MVP (among the singers)" because MVP by definition refers to one best person. It will not mean "among the MVPs" unless it clearly says something like MVPの中で言ったら.